# How to compile storyboard in playground

Tags: ios, xcode8, swift-playground, xcode-storyboard

I am creating an app on playground, I added a Main.storyboard file in this project. but when its compile, it gives me the following error.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle
```

so i start thinking that it maybe some typo, so that's why this error generates. but this was not the problem, so i start searching on google, and stackoverflow, but did not find the solution about my problem. There are many questions on stackoverflow with the following content however, each has a very specific scenario.

then i find a playground project from github, in which the developer added a main storyboard and its compiling perfectly, but its extension is Main.storyboardc. then i search about storyboardc extension. so i understand its a compile storyboard.
then for just checking i double tap the the Main.storyboard and change its name to Main.storyboadc. then the following error generates

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard
```

Now at this point I am sure that i have to compile my storyboard first then it will add in my playground, because with out  .storyboardc extension, it did not even find the Main storyboard. as i stated above.
so again i already check all the material on stackoverflow, each has a very specific scenario. so guide me how to compile main.storyboard.

Answer (score 6):

The command `ibtool` will do exactly this for you.

So for example, you can run 
`ibtool --compile Main.storyboardc Main.storyboard` inside the terminal.
After that, all relevant files (Info.plist and .nib files) will be created inside the Main.storyboardc.

Now you can take that `.storyboardc` file and place it inside a project and reference the files inside the storyboard as you normally would.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
```

A `.storyboardc` file is nothing more than a group of nib files.

For more information have a look at the manual page `man ibtool`